# Why should I buy a domain? Can I have my own website without registering?

Tags: html, asp.net, web, web-hosting

I have this question on my mind for a very long time. Why should I buy a domain? If I don't buy a domain, will I face legal Issues? Even if I buy a domain, where does my website name gets registered? Why can't I keep my domain name forever? Does popular websites like Google, Facebook too buy their domains every year? If yes, from who?
Let us assume that I have all facilities to host my website of my own, like 24/7 server, etc., Even after that should I have to buy a domain?

Could anyone help me in solving my doubt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to this incident described in [Google paid this much to the guy who briefly owned Google.com](https://www.cnet.com/news/what-did-google-pay-the-guy-who-briefly-owned-google-com/), apparently, yes, companies do pay for their domains and may loose it.

If you've a hosting facility, you will need to reserve a public static IP address from an ISP and pay for it, at this point people can reach your website by typing in its IP, as you can reach Google through http://216.58.198.78

Registering a domain name is a process described in [Domain Name Registration Process | ICANN](https://whois.icann.org/en/domain-name-registration-process) and it is not available to public.

And here is a good read: [Can you register a domain name directly with ICANN instead of through a middleman?](https://www.thesitewizard.com/domain/register-with-icann-sans-middlemen.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes. You need to buy it if anyone else that you should be able to reach your server via that address. DNS  (Domain Name System) is the thing that translates a name (e.g. "www.google.com") to an IP address, which your computer connects to.

I would recommend trying do find a Domain Name Registrar for your domain (there are several per top-level domain, i.e. .com, .org, .no, .in, etc), and read a bit about how it works.

Examples of registrars are https://godaddy.com, https://domains.google, and several thousands of others.